# Blank screen when using http in webView iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift / iOS and am trying to use webView to be able to view a url. Searching this site and countless others I managed to be able to access google by using

```
var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
```

This works fine with "https" but does not work if I use "http". 
Is the "s" a security setting? How can I view sites with a "URL scheme" of "http".
Hope you can assist.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView? = nil

    var webView:WKWebView?

    //instatiating the webView
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Loading and showing a web-page
        var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        //var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with http://stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: have you set the delegate of WebView

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying this with iOS9? Watch the first 5 minutes of [Session 706 - Security and Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=706)

Answer (score 1):

Editing the info.plist and adding App Transport Security Settings and add to that Allow Arbitrary Loads and the Boolean = yes

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in your info.plist
info.plist is an XML file so you can place this code more or less anywhere inside the file.
this is the configuration to allow a specific domain to use HTTP instead of HTTPS:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
 <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with http://stackoverflow.com. it worked for me

```
        var url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/")

        //var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")//Comment this

        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)

        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
```

Comment: Hi @Meet {(http://stackoverflow.com)} did not work for me. But: {(https://stackoverflow.com)} worked ok. Hi RahuMishra Can you elaborate on how to "set the delegate for webView.  I have a ReferencingOutlet from containerView to ViewController. Thanks

Comment: When I added the s it worked ok for stackOverflow but it did not work without the s.

Comment: Hi @Filip Radelic I was using iOS8.3 and have now upgraded to iOS8.4. I viewed Session 706 - it mentions "by default, apps linked against iOS9 X10.11 cannot make unprotected http connections". Are you aware of a setting in iOS that will allow me to view http web sites in iOS8.4. Is my issue a bug in iOS?